# Is Millman's Theorem approach here correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The question is as follows:

[image]

My answer is as follows:

[image]

However, per the source the answer is:

[image]

Comment: Millman's is good for this but you need to show the working between your first two lines. Maybe some rounding errors can account for the small difference?

Comment: You keep asking the same question over and over again: "Can I / Should I use this method on a circuit to analyse it", and the answer is always the same: if you've got all the terms you need for that, yes, you can. If it's easy to solve, then yes you should. I don't think you need another answer.

Comment: Is this your source? https://electronicspani.com/millmans-theorem-for-ac-networks/

Comment: I'm suspicious of your question. Did you really take the time to carefully typeset your equations, even coloring some of the text red? **Show us your work.** If you got this answer from another source, **give us the link**. If you can't tell us where you got the answer then I suggest you take your questions elsewhere.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the OP did show his work, and it's correct. It's the source that is wrong and this is a legit question since it ask for confirmation about what is wrong teaching.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the OP took the picture from the website detailed by Sredni Vashtar (see above) and there isn't anything there that I can see that looks like his carefully typeset equations so I think we should give the benefit of the doubt here.

Comment: Wow... that electronicspani website is... bad. OMAR; really, if this is what you learn with, find a different resource. This will hurt you for years to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's of any help, I also get the same numbers as you. I calculated \$V_L\$ to be 4.7646 volts and I got a current magnitude of 1.0654 amps. I didn't bother to calculate the phase angles.

> *Is Millman's Theorem approach here correct?*

Yes it is and I expect that the "formal" answer given has got some rounding errors. They also appear to be calculating \$V_L\$ to be exactly 5 volts and that is a mistake. I'd consider changing your text books if I were you because that's two questions you have delivered where the formal answer is either wrong or dubious.

Comment: yes, if you look at the website I linked above, they computed the voltage disregarding the last branch, and then erroneously attached the branch to the 'Millman equivalent circuit'. I get the same results you and the op get. It's the website that messed things up.